# Retrieving the current bound template markup of a component

Tags: angular

Can an Angular 2 component with a data-bound template retrieve a string of the current state of its inner markup?

Example:
If the Component MyComponent has the template

```
<div>{{foo}}</div>
```

And MyComponent.foo has the current value of "Hello"

Can I retrieve a string inside MyComponent that contains

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

?
It should also work with more complex binding examples like loops etc.

I feel like it should be pretty straightforward, e.g. fetching innerHTML but I don't know what's the "clean" way of doing this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've tried using the ElementRef, but this has worked for me:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

{ Component, ElementRef } from '@angular2/core';
         @Component({
               selector: 'my-app',
               template: `
               <p>Hello World</p>
               {{title}}
               `
    })

export class MyAppComponent {

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
   var html = this.el.nativeElement.InnerHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a **directive** for it so **I can use it anywhere**. It will also work with loop.

**NOTE** : ***Just click the element and check browser's console***.

---

**Working DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/yYVMXQT5SfjpCThF6sp7?p=preview**

```
import { Component,Directive,ElementRef,Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector:'[fetchHTML]',
    host: {
    '(click)':'GetInnerHTML()',
   },
})

export class GetInnerHTML{ 

  constructor(private el:ElementRef,private rd: Renderer){}

  GetInnerHTML()
  {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {service} from './service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
    <p fetchHTML>Hello</p>

    <div *ngFor="let m of data" fetchHTML>{{m}}</div>
    `

})
export class AppComponent { 
  data=["one","two","three"];
}
```